# Determining flexural modulus by performing 3 point bending test using hollow cylindrical tube

Tags: elasticity, moment-of-inertia

I would like to decide the flexural modulus of the material of plastic tube by performing 3 point bending test according to the ASTM D 790 procedure.
In ASTM D 790, the form of the specimen is supposed to be a rectangular bar and the length of the support span and rate of crosshead motion are to be calculated based on the depth of the specimen. 
 But my problem is that “I have only a hollow cylindrical tube as a specimen”.
So, I plan to do the test by hypothesizing that my specimen is a rectangular bar with depth and width are equal to Outer Diameter of the tube. 
So, my question is that is this approach mentioned above is appropriate or is there more appropriate approach like hypothesizing that my specimen is a rectangular bar having the same moment of inertia of the hollow cylindrical tube?
Any advice and comment will be helpful.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It is not _mass moment of inertia_, but _area moment_ you are talking about, right?

Answer (score 1):

The area moment of a solid square with side $a$ is $$I_{\square} = \frac{a^4}{12} $$

The area moment of hollow tube with outside diameter $D$ and inside diameter $d$ is

$$ I_{\circledcirc} =\pi \frac{D^4-d^4}{64} $$

To find the equivalent square side $a$ equate $I_{\square}=I_{\circledcirc}$ with the dimensions of tube you have.

If the material is the same then $E I_{\square} = E I_{\circledcirc}$ and thus the deflection $$\delta = \frac{\ell^3}{48 E I} F$$

is the same for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar test about a month ago. These are the equations we were given for the lab.

*note these equations are for solid cylinders*

strain = $12\dfrac{dr}{L^2}$    and    stress = $\dfrac{PL}{\pi r^3}$

Where:

$d$ is the deflection of the rod under load (distance)

$r$ is the radius of the rod (distance)

$L$ is the span between the supports (distance)

$P$ is the applied load (force)

This assumes you apply the load at the center between the two supports.

We weren't told how these equations were derived, so I can't help with the exact equations, but hopefully this gets you closer. : )

Comment: Please try to use math formatting with `$...$`. It helps greatly with readability.

Comment: The tube is going to "crush" somewhat adding to the measured deflection, providing an underestimate for the flexular modulus.

Answer (score 0):

In  ASTM D 790 special provisions have been provided for large span to beam depth ratios which are pronouncedly present in your case.

I would recommend to find a way to block off the two ends of your cylinder specimen to prevent local buckling at the ends or elastic deformations turning the end circle into a flat oval or plastic crimping there.

The second area moment for a solid rectangular beam is  $$ I = B.H^3/{12}  $$
 and I of a hollow cylinder as mentioned in one of the answers is $$I = \pi \frac{D^4-d^4}{64}   $$

The deflection for a prismatic beam is $$ \delta = \frac {P.L^3} {48EI}   $$

By finding the rectangular beam with the same I and assuming you have blocked the ends of your cylinder, you can calculate flexural modules.